# Second page of pagination displaying ALL results

Tags: php, pagination

been stuck on this for hours.
I have a simple (I think) pagination PHP code here working fine for the first page - meaning I get the correct amount of pages displayed and the correct results displayed. Code:

```
<?php
$query = $_POST ['query'];
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    mysql_select_db("asset_catalog",$link);
$q=("SELECT COUNT(*) \"total\" FROM assets WHERE Description LIKE '%$query%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%$query%'");
$ros=mysql_query($q,$link) or die(mysqli_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ros);
$total=$row['total'];
$dis=15;
$total_page=ceil($total/$dis);
$page_cur=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
$k=($page_cur-1)*$dis;

$q=("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE Description LIKE '%$query%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%$query%' limit $k,$dis");
$ros=mysql_query($q,$link);

    echo "<table border='0'>

        <tr>

        </tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))

        {
            if (($i % 5) == 0) echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['Image']."' id='queryimg'><br>
             <a href='details.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' style='color: #fff;'>{$row[Description]}</a></td>";
                if (($i % 5) == 4) echo "</tr>";
                $i++;
        }

        if ( $i > 0 && ($i-1) % 3 < 2) echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";

?>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 320px;">
<?php
if($page_cur>1)
{
    echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur-1).'" style="cursor:pointer;color:green;" ><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous "></a>';
}
else
{
  echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous ">';
}
for($i=1;$i<$total_page;$i++)
{
    if($page_cur==$i)
    {
        echo ' <input style="background-color:green;border:2px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="'.$i.'"> ';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.$i.'"> <input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="'.$i.'"> </a>';
    }
}
if($page_cur<$total_page)
{
    echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur+1).'"><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Next "></a>';
}
else
{
 echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="   Next ">';
}?>
```

The problem is if I click on the second page it displays ALL results in the DB - not the results that should be in the second page. Additionally, if I have say 3 pages initially, once I go to the second page it shows me there are 70 pages aka(all the db)

I'm sure there is a quick fix for this but for the life of me I can't figure it out.
Any help, advice would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between pages you lose your `$_POST['query']` .

Instead of

```
$query = $_POST ['query'];
```

do

```
$query = (isset($_POST ['query']))?$_POST['query']:$_GET['query'];
```

or use

```
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
```

AND

in your pagination link replace

```
'<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur-1).'" style
```

with

```
'<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur-1).'&query='.$query.'" style
```

Comment: Octavian: Thanks so much! that did it. Very much appreciated! So much to learn still but glad to have the forum to look for answers. Thanks again!

Comment: Try to use MySQLi as MySQL extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Also escape your $query variable before using it in a SQL Query with mysqli_real_escape_string(). I also recommend using a Framework, pagination, escaping and database platform switching are trivial tasks for frameworks as Codeigniter, Laravel etc.

Comment: You know, I tried with MySQLi but it won't work. Everything works fine with MySQL but once I change it to MySQLi extensions it does not work. I'm baffled.